# Is there a way to upgrade the HTML WebBrowser control in WPF?

Tags: html, wpf

So it looks like the WPF HTML Viewer control (WebBrowser) runs on an IE 7 framework.  That is terrible and sad.  Is it possible to upgrade my control in my project to be more current?

Comment: set [FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx) registry for your app exe name to whichever version you need

Comment: For faster reference one of the questions has this link to a nice walkthrough by Rick Strahl  http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version